# Как открыть свойства драйвера одним кликом?

Tags: delphi

Как открыть свойства драйвера одним кликом? Считать размеры бумаги с драйвера и вставить их в edit

Comment: @kirik1982, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 2):

Пуск | Панель управления | Устройства и принтеры | Правый клик на принтер | Настройка печати

Считывайте и вставляйте куда хотите.

Answer (score 0):

```
  uses
    Printers, WinSpool;
//**
    function PrintDriverExists: boolean;//проверяем установлен ли принтер
  var
    Flags, Count, NumInfo: dword;
    Level: Byte;
  begin
    Count := 0;
    try
    if Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then
    begin
      Flags := PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS or PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL;
      Level := 4;
    end else
    begin
      Flags := PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL;
      Level := 5;
    end;
    EnumPrinters(Flags, nil, Level, nil, 0, Count, NumInfo);
  except
  end;
  result := (count > 0);
 end;
//**
     function PrintSizeHEIGHTmm: Integer;//получаем высоту в миллиметрах
     var
     Y: integer;
      begin
       Y:= GetDeviceCaps(printer.Handle, LOGPIXELSY);
       Result:= round(GetDeviceCaps(printer.Handle, PHYSICALHEIGHT)*25.4/Y);
      end;
//**    
     function PrintSizeWIDTHmm: Integer;//получаем ширину в миллиметрах
     var
     X: integer;
     begin
      X:= GetDeviceCaps(printer.Handle, LOGPIXELSX);
      Result:= round(GetDeviceCaps(printer.Handle, PHYSICALWIDTH)*25.4/X);
     end;
//**    
     //Выводим в Edit
    if PrintDriverExists = true then
    begin
    Edit1.Text:=IntToStr(PrintSizeHEIGHTmm)+' X '+IntToStr(PrintSizeWIDTHmm);
    end;
```